# How to enable ReadWriteMany access mode using an io2 EBS Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs

I want to enable `ReadWriteMany` access mode in EKS Persistent Volume. Came accross io2 volumetype by EBS AWS. SO using io2 type volume

storage_class.yaml

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: io2
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  type: io2
  iopsPerGB: "200"
```

persistent_volume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4
    volumeID: <IO2 type volume ID>
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: io2
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

pv_claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pv
  storageClassName: io2
```

When 3 replicas of pods are deployed across 2 nodes in same AZ, 2 replicas (on one node) successfully mounts to the io2 volume and starts running but third replica on another node does not mount to volume.

> Error -> Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes['']

Also, I want to understand if io2 type volumes are meant to be mount to multiple nodes(EC2 instances in same AZ as volume) in EKS with ReadWriteMany access mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like there is [open feature request on kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/449) repo but no progress on this. So I guess that it is not supported at the moment but you can monitor the issue for updates.