# AWS EBS as Kubernetes StorageClass with ReadWriteMany mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, storage

I want to setup Kubernetes StorageClass that supports ReadWriteMany AccessMode with **AWS EBS** storage.

AWS EBS previously had the problem that with type: **gp2** or **gp3** as they **do not support** **Multi-Attach** for multiple instances and only one instance could be attached, but now it has types like  **io1** and **io2**, which **support Multi-Attach**.

Up until now I have searched and found only solutions that make you force all pods to a single node, which is not possible for me as that affects scaling, or make you use AWS EFS, which also is not desired, as costs more (in some places read that it costs even 10x more in certain situations)

Is there any info on AWS EBS ReadWriteMany Access Mode being available or any discussions about it?

Comment: This has been also answered here (unfortunately ... no progress has been made so far): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67197235/how-to-enable-readwritemany-access-mode-using-an-io2-ebs-volume

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not possible ([Kubernetes issue reference copied from 67197235](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/449))

The problem seems to be that ext4 and similar filesystems on block storage are not designed to be managed by multiple machines and that creates fundamental limitations. True ReadWriteMany seems to be very unlikely to be implemented in a reliable way over EBS.

This is probably the main reason why [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) is recommended on AWS for this purpose because that was designed to be a proper network file system that can be shared in a multi-write way between multiple machines/pods.