# Single EBS volume shared by multiple EC2 nodes in a EKS/K8s cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs

I would like to determine if a data storage scenario described below is possible with AWS EKS/Kubernetes. Here is the spec:

- Application data exists on a single [multi-attach EBS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html) (io2).
- The volume is provisioned and seeded with data ahead of time. The data are read-only.
- The EKS cluster uses this EBS volume to create a static PersistentVolume object. This PV is mounted by multiple pods in the deployment.
- We would like to be able to scale this deployment across multiple EC2 nodes, so the PV must be mountable across all EC2 nodes in the deployment.

The goal here is to use the multi-attach EBS drive as a stand-in for a database. We want data to be accessible by several EC2 nodes, see note [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html).

As far as I can tell, the EBS driver for EKS does not support multi-attach drives ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67197235/how-to-enable-readwritemany-access-mode-using-an-io2-ebs-volume/67210073#67210073), [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/449)).

So then my other option is to directly configure the nodes in the auto-scaling group to mount the EBS volume as part of their initial start-up. Then, use a `local` PV type in the K8s manifest.

Is this second option technically viable?

###### Foot Notes

[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html) Why are we not using an actual database, or an EFS? Because they are too slow. We have a bit of a special use case, where we are trying to establish a multi-gigabyte-per-second read rate between compute and storage, and on AWS that can only (?) be achieved with an IO optimized EBS drive directly attached to an EC2 node.

Comment: As you seem to have found, you can't use multi-attach volumes with EKS clusters. But it should be very possible to achieve "multi-gigabyte-per-second" read rates on AWS RDS... You can provision the same amount of IOPS in RDS as on EC2.

Comment: @sytech I did not think of that. The data we have is not relational, it's a multidimensional matrix of type m(i,j,k) = d, so RDS isn't very practical, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.25.0 of AWS EBS CSI Driver just released includes this functionality. Perhaps this is now a possibility for you?

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I moved in another direction since then. I scrapped K8 in favor of directly mounting containers on Autoscaling groups as part of instance set up with user-data (the same user-data script also mounts the EBS volume). It's not as elegant as K8, I suppose, but it worked out well for our use case.

Comment: @tvandinther Does this support attaching volumes to more than 1 node in the same cluster or only across different clusters?

Comment: @rock'nrolla I do not know the answer to that one unfortunately. I came across this release when looking up the original question as I was also researching some possible solutions to a similar problem as OP. I haven't got around to giving it a test run. Considering this is for a CSI driver, I would presume you can multi-attach to nodes (and by extension, pods). Otherwise, in theory the AWS support of multi-attach should be sufficient for a multi-cluster attach (1 per cluster).